# iOS - Add Certificate to trusted certificates

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate, keychain, root-certificate

How can I make a self-signed certificate as trusted for making https requests from an objective-c iOS app.

Basically looking something like adding my certificate to app bundle and mark it as trusted root certificate for that device.

Comment: If it were possible it would be a huge security risk

Comment: Then, how can we make TLS connections with servers having self-signed certs ?

Comment: That's kind of the point. A self-signed certificate isn't very secure. You need to establish a trust of the signing root, but that has to happen outside of your app. It either has to be done manually by the user or via an MDM/Apple Configurator profile

Comment: Your other option would be to reduce the ATS settings so that the self-signed certificate was accepted. See [tjis discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87932)